# In django-rest-framework, serialize model from a different class

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am writing a point-of-sale (POS) system in Django. I have basic functionality, and before I go adding any more complexity I am trying to clean up my code.

As part of that effort I am moving my AJAX calls to be part of an API with django-rest-framework.

In my models I have a Transaction that represents all the items a customer has purchased. Each individual purchase in that Transaction is a LineItem. In my TransactionViewSet api class I have a function named ring_plu. It takes in the UPC and quantity, adds that item as a LineItem to the UPC, and then I want it to return that new LineItem. The code looks like this.

```
TransactionViewSet
    @detail_route(
        methods=['post'],
        renderer_classes=[renderers.StaticHTMLRenderer]
    )
    def ring_upc(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        upc = request.POST['upc']
        quantity = request.POST['quantity']
        if len(upc) != 12:
            return Response('Invalid UPC', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        grocery = get_object_or_404(Grocery, upc=upc)
        transaction = self.get_object()
        line_item = transaction.create_line_item(grocery, quantity)
        serializer = LineItemSerializer(line_item, context={'request':request})
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I am calling /api/transactions/10/ring_upc/ with the POST body `{'upc':'071990095314','quantity':1}` and requesting an application/json response. All I get back is this.

> urlcodequantityscaledescriptionpricestatustransactionitem

I have played around with a few different options for the serializers, but I cannot seem to get the serializer to work correctly.

Here are some other parts of the code that may be useful.

**serializers.py**

```
class LineItemSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = LineItem
```

**models.py**

```
class LineItem(models.Model):
    transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transaction)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=0)
    scale = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=4, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=17, decimal_places=2)
    item = models.ForeignKey('inventory.Item')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=8, default='ACTIVE')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.scale) + ' x ' + self.description + ' ' +\
            self.description

    def total(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity

    def cancel(self):
        self.status = 'INACTIVE'
```

Comment: Is that all of your LineItemSerializer code?

Comment: Yes. This is all that is needed for the crud operations to work and to return serial line items from the lineitem API controller.

Comment: I would be interested in what this line returns:  `line_item = transaction.create_line_item(grocery, quantity)` but if I were you, I'd insert a breakpoint (`import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`) at the beginning of that view and step through it in the debugger. You're likely to find out more about your data that way.

Comment: It appears to be the LineItem that I was expecting.

    (Pdb) n

    > /home/david/code/orthosie/register/api_views.py(71)ring_upc()

    -> serializer = LineItemSerializer(line_item, context={'request':request})

    (Pdb) line_item

    <LineItem: LineItem object>

    (Pdb) line_item.id

    64

    (Pdb) line_item.code

    '071990095314'

    (Pdb) line_item.price

    Decimal('0.99')

    (Pdb)

Comment: Your transaction ViewSet is missing it's inheritance params. Can you please fix it?

Comment: Whats that status of the response?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in `renderers.StaticHTMLRenderer`.

From [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#statichtmlrenderer) this renderer is:

> A simple renderer that simply returns pre-rendered HTML. Unlike other renderers, the data passed to the response object should be a string representing the content to be returned.

Renderer expects plain text in response data. However it receives `dict` and transforms it to string simply iterating over it.

You can simply remove `renderer_classes=[renderers.StaticHTMLRenderer]` from `@detail_route` arguments.

Comment: Nailed it. This problem was a serious blocker for progress on this project. Thanks for the help.